# How can I upload image to photo hosting and use in my laravel project

Tags: mysql, laravel, image, redirect, upload

So, I want in my laravel project to press the upload button, but to upload the image to a photo host, it doesn't matter which, and then this link to go to my database.
How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](https://www.codewall.co.uk/upload-image-to-database-using-laravel-tutorial-with-example/).

Hoping you find your answer there.